# Do psychopaths shun physical touch?

Tags: abnormal-psychology

I have in the back in my mind the idea that psychopaths don't like to be touched physically. However a quick google search doesn't tell me whether the idea is founded in good research or I picked it up incorrectly.

Do psychopaths shun physical touch and close contact?

Comment: Could it be because normal people shun from touching psychopaths, kind of like in a Beauty & Beast story